# I have an issue when I want to edit my product list and i am getting this error Cannot read property 'title' of null

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an issue after my data is stored in db and I want to edit it. It is not showing data and I am getting cannot read property error.

**Html**

**admin-products.component.html**

```
<p>
  <a routerLink="/admin/products/new" class="btn btn-primary">New Products</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let p of products$ | async">
      <td>{{ p.title }}</td>
      <td>{{ p.price }}</td>
      <td><a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/', p.$key]">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**product-form.component.html**

If I check error link in console it is showing an error at all input field. I think mostly error may b here ?

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input
          #title="ngModel"
          [(ngModel)]="product.title"
          name="title"
          id="title"
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          required
        />
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="title.touched && title.invalid">
          Title is required.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"> $ </span>
          <input
            #price="ngModel"
            [(ngModel)]="product.price"
            name="price"
            id="price"
            type="number"
            class="form-control"
            required
            [min]="0"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="price.touched && price.invalid">
          <div *ngIf="price.errors.required">Price is required.</div>
          <div *ngIf="price.errors.min">Price should be 0 or higher.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select
          #category="ngModel"
          [(ngModel)]="product.category"
          name="category"
          id="category"
          class="form-control"
          required
        >
          <option value=""></option>
          <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.$key">
            {{ c.name }}
          </option>
        </select>
        <div
          class="alert alert-danger"
          *ngIf="category.touched && category.invalid"
        >
          Category is required
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="imageUrl">Image Url</label>
        <input
          #imageUrl="ngModel"
          [(ngModel)]="product.imageUrl"
          name="imageUrl"
          id="imageUrl"
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          required
          url
        />
        <div
          class="alert alert-danger"
          *ngIf="imageUrl.touched && imageUrl.invalid"
        >
          <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.required">Image is required</div>
          <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.url">Please enter a vaild URL</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img
        class="card-img-top"
        [src]="product.imageUrl"
        *ngIf="product.imageUrl"
      />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.title }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{ product.price | currency: 'USD':true }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**product-form.component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from 'src/app/category.service';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/product.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent {
  categories$;
  product = {};

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService
  ) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();

    // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
    let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    // tslint:disable-next-line:curly
    if (id)
      this.productService.get(id).valueChanges().take(1).subscribe(p => (this.product = p));
  }

  save(product) {
    this.productService.create(product);
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
  }
}
```

**product-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  products$: AngularFireList<any[]>;
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.products$ = this.db.list('/products');
  }
  create(product) {
    return this.products$.push(product);
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.db.list('/products').valueChanges();
  }

  get(productId) {
    return this.db.object('/products/' + productId);
  }
}
```

I have tried this method by using *ngIf , [ngModel]="product?.title"

> `<input *ngIf="title">`

Comment: Hi perhaps check the stack trace to see where the problem is happening?

Comment: If you want the check, it is `ngIf="p"`. But you should really check why your observable is giving you `null` products.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to wrap your form with ng-container ?

product-form.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent {
  categories$;
  product = null;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService
  ) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();

    // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
    let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    // tslint:disable-next-line:curly
    if (id)
      this.productService.get(id).valueChanges().take(1).subscribe(p => (this.product = p));
  }

  save(product) {
    this.productService.create(product);
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
  }
}
```

product-form.component.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <ng-container *ngIf="product">
       <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">
       <!-- YOUR CODE -->
       </form>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ya I have tried this but it is not working. i am getting this error Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError

Comment: To check if your observable is triggering correctly, could you put a console.log(p) inside the subscribe and give some feedback ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
export class ProductFormComponent {
  categories$;
  product = {
               "title": '',
               "price": '', 
               "category": '',
               "imageUrl": '',                
            };



constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private categoryService: CategoryService,
        private productService: ProductService
      ) {
        this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();

        // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
        let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        // tslint:disable-next-line:curly
        if (id)
          this.productService.get(id).valueChanges().take(1).subscribe(p => (this.product = p));
      }

      save(product) {
        this.productService.create(product);
        this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
      }
    }
```

The reason it is failing because

```
this.productService.get(id).valueChanges().take(1).subscribe(p => (this.product = p));
```

the above line will take time to get the response from the firebase, In the meantime, the HTML component will be rendered before that, so it is trying to access product object in the HTML component, since there is no title, price, category, and imageUrl in product object it will cause the error. So assign the empty values, later it is updated once you receive the response